# Are there languages that mark different types of volition or causality morphologically?

Tags: morphology, verbs, inflection

A simple event description such as "The boy jumped" does not necessarily imply anything about the speaker's understanding of the cause of the event or of the volition of the agent. I can say "The boy jumped" and mean that he was caused to jump involuntarily (e.g. by a sudden noise), or that he jumped of his own volition for a specific purpose (e.g. to reach something), or that he jumped of his own volition but for no reason or cause I can see, etc. Are there languages that mark such differences with verbal morphology, in the way that some languages mark evidentiality (which seems like a similar type of category)?

I'm not asking about argument structure-changing operations like causative forms; I'm asking if there are languages that inflectionally contrast forms of the same verb, with the same argument structure, with morphs that might be glossed as e.g. "involuntary action", "purposive action", "unknown cause", etc.

Comment: I know ***causative*** is a linguistics term but is causative vs not causative really called ***causality***? I've seen ***causal*** and ***causation*** - maybe that last term would work best as the general noun for this in linguistics?

Comment: From reading the question body I don't think the wording in the title is accurate. If somebody makes you do something that's not any kind of volitional, so rather than talking about different kinds of volition I think you want to compare volitional and causal. (I do actually wonder if there are different kinds of volitional marked in a language now - but it seems not to be what you're asking about on this occasion.)

Comment: @hippietrail I wasn't using "causality" to refer to causative vs. non-causative; that would be "causativity". Since volition and causation are pretty closely intertwined semantically, I'm asking about both, so I chose the wording in the title to reflect that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. [Lushootseed](http://www.ethnologue.com/language/lut/%2a%2a%2aEDITION%2a%2a%2a) has two different object pronoun paradigms, depending on whether the action predicated was performed volitionally or not. For example:

- ʔu-k̉ʷəɬ-**əd**-čəd tə-qʷu 'I poured the water'
  `Narr`-*pour/spill*-`3DOVolit`-`1sAg` `Def`-*water*
- ʔu-k̉ʷəɬ-**dxʷ**-čəd tə-qʷu 'I spilled the water'
  `Narr`-*pour/spill*-`3DONonvol`-`1sAg` `Def`-*water*

and contrasting with the intransitive

- ʔu-k̉ʷəɬ tə-qʷu 'the water spilled'
  `Narr`-*pour/spill* `Def`-*water*

Or

- ʔu-pus-**uds**-čəxʷ  'You threw something at me (and hit me)'
  `Narr`-*throw*-`1sDOVolit`-`2sAg`
- ʔu-pus-**dubš**-čəxʷ  'You threw something at me (and it happened to hit me)'
  `Narr`-*throw*-`1sDONonvol`-`2sAg`

Or

- ʔu-kʷa-**ad**-čəd  'I dropped it'
  `Narr`-*drop*-`3DOVolit`-`1sAg`
- ʔu-kʷa-**dxʷ**-čəd  'I dropped it'
  `Narr`-*drop*-`1sDONonvol`-`1sAg`

Comment: Thanks! I had a feeling the languages of the Americas would come to the rescue.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Georgian and Japanese mark causation in their verb morphology too. Other languages seem to contrast what might be thought of as a marked "volitional" with an unmarked. Compare "I will" and "I shall" in the future - I think German is an even clearer example.

Comment: Causation is commonly marked; volitional causation is more likely a matter of vocabulary choice, modification, intonation, pragmatics, or some combination of the above. And nobody I've ever encountered has used a distinction between _will_ and _shall_ to indicate volition; in speech, either is contracted in use.

Comment: What is "volitional causation"? Something like *"I **will** make you do it!"*?

Comment: Yes the will/shall thing has pretty much died out in the English varieties I'm familiar with, but apparently that's pretty recent - recent enough that many people would know of it.

Comment: The difference between _pour_ and _spill_ in English. Both are causative, but _pour_ is volitional, while _spill_ is nonvolitional.

Comment: Ah I found a definition used in semantics via Google Books: **“Volitional causation”** means that the actions of the Causer are volitional, but not that he necessarily wants the actual result of his actions.

Comment: Apologies if any of my comments confused matters here due to my misunderstanding `)-:` I was thinking strictly morphology and not semantics and was not familiar with this term.

Comment: Oh, I think that addendum is optional. The difference between _I spilled the coffee in his lap_ and _I poured the coffee in his lap_ is pretty straightforward.

Comment: Has anyone done a cross-linguistic survey of such volitionality/control marking systems? It would be interesting to see how both the categories themselves and the morphological means used to mark them might vary across languages.

Comment: Probly you could start with Chapters 77 ([Semantic Distinctions of Evidentiality](http://wals.info/chapter/77)) and 78 ([Coding of Evidentiality](http://wals.info/chapter/78)) of WALS, both  by Ferdinand de Haan. There are lots of references and examples.